# Optimize filtering of dynamic list by looking at string properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datagrid with many columns and above the table there is a textbox where a search string can be entered. When text is entered in the textbox I want the table to be filtered. Multiple search terms can be entered separated by space, all search terms should be present in the remaining rows.  I want the filter method to search only in string properties in the supplied list. The code below works as I want, but is painfully slow because of the nested loops.
I'm struggling trying to convert this to LINQ as I guess that would really help performance.

Bonus: If the method could be made so it accepts list of any type, not just dynamic would be even better.

```
public List<dynamic> FilterList(List<dynamic> list, string searchterms)
{
    string[] words = searchterms.ToUpper().Split(' ');

    var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(list.FirstOrDefault());
    List<PropertyDescriptor> stringProps = new();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            stringProps.Add(prop);
        }
    }
    Log("Properties: " + timer.Elapsed);

    List<dynamic> filteredList = list.ToList();

    timer.Restart();
    foreach (dynamic item in list)
    {
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            bool hit = false;
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in stringProps)
            {
                try
                {
                    string propval = prop.GetValue(item);
                    if (propval == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (propval.ToUpper().Contains(word))
                    {
                        hit = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
            if (!hit)
            {
                filteredList.Remove(item);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    Log("Looping: " + timer.Elapsed);
    return filteredList;
}
```

Time measurement output. List has a few hundred posts and about 15 string properties.

```
Properties: 00:00:00.1143073
Looping:    00:00:00.0632542
Properties: 00:00:00.0000831
Looping:    00:00:00.0541464
Properties: 00:00:00.0000292
Looping:    00:00:00.3080632
Properties: 00:00:00.0000298
Looping:    00:00:00.3394484
```

I have the same functionality for types with known properties which is much quicker:

```
public static List<MyType> FilterList(List<MyType> list, string searchterms)
{
    List<MyType> filteredlist = list.ToList();
    string[] words = searchterms.ToUpper().Split(' ');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        filteredlist = filteredlist.Where(x => x.Prop1.ToUpper().Contains(word)
                                            || x.Prop2.ToUpper().Contains(word)
                                            || x.Prop3.ToUpper().Contains(word)).ToList();
    }
    return filteredlist;
}
```

Edit: Added time measurement

Edit 2: Found that I used the complete list of properties, instead of the one with only string properties. This made a huge difference for performance. The loops went from ~300 ms to ~30 ms. Try - Catch is probably expensive (I believe only one of the columns was not of string type in the example data).

Edit 3: What was taking most of the time was that exceptions were getting thrown from this line:
`string propval = prop.GetValue(item);`
When there were empty values, they were of type System.DBNull and could not be assigned to a string variable. An exception was thrown and this apparently took much time.
Changing the line to like below this made it much faster, then the empty string is returned for DBNull.Value and no exception is thrown.
`string propval = prop.GetValue(item).ToString();`
After this change, performance for the loops went from ~30 ms to ~1 ms.

Comment: It's slow because of Reflection. A distant second is the temporary strings generated by all the `ToUpper()` and `Split()` operations. Why are you using reflection in the first place? What does `list` contain? As for `FilterList`, you can make case-insensitive `Contains` and `Equals` calls. This will use far less memory, also improving speed. You're still performing a brute-force search though, scanning all objects and properties

Comment: Are you trying to create generic search functionality for a reusable grid component? The types don't change from one invocation to the next, which means you can identify a type's text properties in advance and cache them. There's no need to recalculate the PropertyDescriptors every time

Comment: I did some time measurements while entering three characters in the search box, and there already seems to be some caching going on for the properties. The first time took some time but after that it was really quick, so it's really the loops that's taking the time here.
1: Properties: 00:00:00.1426144 ms. 
Looping: 00:00:00.0874366 ms. 
2: Properties: 00:00:00.0000200 ms. 
Looping: 00:00:00.0588289 ms. 
3: Properties: 00:00:00.0000356 ms. 
Looping: 00:00:00.3282242 ms. 
I also tried case insensitive search instead, but that made no noticeable difference.

Comment: These numbers are so small they're meaningless - they're affected by noise. Use BenchmarkDotNet to get correct results that can handle noise. `I also tried case insensitive search instead, but that made no noticeable difference.` that means your test was wrong, and didn't actually include the cost of allocation *and garbage collection*. Strings in .NET are immutable so every string modification creates a new string. This has to be allocated and then GC'd. The 30x perf improvements in .NET Core came from eliminating unnecessary allocations like this.

Comment: If you have a *lot* of data to search, it would be better to "index" it by splitting the text in advance and inserting it into dictionaries or hashsets. This way you'd only have to look up the words in those indexes instead of scanning all the objects every time. You'd also avoid splitting and comparing the data every time

Answer (score 0):

You are using `dynamic` and complain about performance? The main purpose of `dynamic` is to make interoperability simpler. There should be no reason to use it in code like this, and it will cause a huge penalty for performance.

I would recommend that you instead pre-compute a single string for each row that contains all the fields that you want to search in. This should let you loop over the search terms, doing a `.Contain` for each one.

One way to make search method for any kind of object is to use generics. For example by using a signature looking something like

```
IEnumerable<T> FilterList<T>(List<T> list, string searchterms,  Func<T, string[]> columnSelector )
```

This lets the caller specify the properties of fields to use, while keeping the overhead low. You may consider if you want the selection method to produce a single string, an array of strings, or take a array of delegates.

Having done similar things I would expect a properly coded linear search to work well up to at least 10k items. But you might want to have some mechanism to delay searching slightly so that you are only searching when the user stops typing for half a second or so.

If you need even better performance you would need to look into some method for indexing your data. You might want to take a look at [lucene.net](https://lucenenet.apache.org/).

Also, whenever talking about performance, a important point is to *measure*, ideally also using a performance profiler that can tell you what parts of the code that is slow. That should give you an idea if you are wasting most of the time doing unnecessary work, or if you need to look into other techniques for improving performance

Comment: Thanks for the answer and suggestions. I would have hoped though that there would be some way to optimize the performance a bit within the limits of this method. For example if it would be possible to use LINQ in some way (assuming that it would increase the performance). It's not performance critical, but a tad slow to wait for the filtering while typing. The lazy option would probably be to add a button next to the textbox to call this method.

Comment: The data comes from SQL database queries using Dapper, and the reason for using dynamic is to not have to create pre-defined types for every SQL query.

Comment: @Fredrik Ekdahl Added some details on how to use generics to do things like this. Note that LINQ is for producing small and compact code. It is *not* for performance, a plain for-loop is often the better alternative for performance sensitive code.